# C# compilation error: "The name does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, sharepoint, compilation, compiler-errors, scope

I'm getting the `name 'result' does not exist in the current context` compilation error in the last few lines of my code.

Any idea what may be causing this?

```
class xmlreader
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
        var lv1s = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("sitecollection")
                   select new
                   {
                       Header = lv1.Attribute("name").Value,
                       Children = lv1.Descendants("level2")
                   };
        foreach (var lv1 in lv1s)
        {
            result.AppendLine(lv1.Header);
            foreach (var lv2 in lv1.Children)
                result.AppendLine("   " + lv2.Attribute("name").Value);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 'result' doesn't appear to be defined in the code you've included.

Comment: Are you sure the `name` attribute exists in lv1 and lv2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code snippet, you never instantiate the "result" variable. Your code miss the following statement:

```
var result=new System.Text.StringBuilder();
```